# Power Automate Desktop Returns "1/1/0001" when using "Get current date and time"

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I am using Power Automate desktop to set up a flow. For this flow I need to get the current date, use it to get the most previous Monday, and get the date from that. When I try to use the "Get current date and time" action in desktop, I set the TimeZone as "specific time zone" then "Country/Region" to my time zone.

The resulting variable, CurrentDateTime, has a value of "1/1/0001 12:00:00AM". Any recommendations on how to fix?

Edit: I've also tried using "System Time Zone" and get the same result

[Get Current Date and Time setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXsSx.png)

[1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM for Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll7Oy.png)

Comment: I looked at hte answer but didn't see a fix for my issue. My problem isn't with conversion at all. The issue is, when I run the 'Get Current date and time' function, it returns something that is obviously not the current date and time. Not sure if it's related, but I'm running the instance on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this is still relevant to you, but maybe it will be for someone else.
I had the same issue when i tried to get CurrentDateTime.

The Reason for the Problem was, that i put the Action in the middle of the Flow.
After i placed it in the beginning of the Flow it got the correct value.

TL;DR: Place the Action at the beginning of the flow.

Hope this works for you too.